# Linear + threshold unified scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to construct a somewhat sophisticated axis that can handle linear data to pixel positions up until a certain value where everything is lobbed into a category and thus has the same data-to-pixel value. For instance, consider a y axis that has the following tick marks:

```
0%, 10%, 20%, 30%, 40%, 50%+
```

In this case, all data above 50% would have the same y-value when plotted.

This is a fairly common chart structure, but I have not seen a d3 implementation, which made it challenging to get off the launch pad. I initially thought that I could use `d3.scaleOrdinal()` or `d3.scaleThreshold`, however I would lose key nuances in the data by doing so. In my data set, it's important to retain the decimals (and the numbers that aren't perfect increments of 10) and plot them precisely. To my knowledge, this can only be achieved through `d3.scaleLinear()`.

My next thought was to create it by using two disjoined axes next to each other to create the illusion of a linear+threshold unified scale.

```
var xScaleLinear = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0,500])

var xScaleThreshold = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .range([500,520])
```

While this may work theoretically, but it implies a lot of complications for the rest of the code. When plotting the data points, each would require an if statement which would point to two totally different scale calls. Not to mention I'd have to add a bunch of aesthetic tweaks like removing only the right-hand end tick of the linear scale, and so forth.

### Question

Can d3 offer anything to help developers unify scales in a more scalable manner? Or should I expect the need to resort to sneaky/makeshift solutions?

Comment: *"In this case, all data above 50% would have the same y-value when plotted"*. But which one? The same as 50%?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yea, truncate everything over 50% to 50%'s y value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truncating everything over 50% to the value of 50% is easily done with [`scale.clamp`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_clamp):

```js
const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 0.5])
  .range([0, 500])
  .clamp(true);

d3.range(11).map(d => console.log(d * 10 + "% in the scale is: " + scale(d / 10)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

On the other hand, if you want a **different** range for those domain values outside the limit, just set a domain and a range with intermediate values. For instance, here the regular domain (from 0 to 50%) goes from 0 to 500 in the range, and everything over 50% will be positioned at 520:

```js
const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 0.5, (0.5 + 1e-6), 1])
  .range([0, 500, 520, 520]);

d3.range(11).map(d=>console.log(d * 10 + "% in the scale is: " + scale(d/10)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```